# How to represent ramifications and conditions using BPMN?

Tags: bpmn

I must represent a process using BPMN 2.0 with conditions that generates ramifications exponentially, and I can't see a way to represent it graphically within the diagram without make it grow that much.

That's a print with the problem, the diagram tends to grow even more. 
[image: BPMN case]

- The option for the company is the same for all 3 companies.
- The type of employee is the same for all 3.
- The configurations are the same for all 3 companies.
- the configuration for the type of emplyee is the same for all 3 companies
- BUT the last configurations are specific for each company, and I define it for each employee.

Is there a way I could simplify this mess?

EDIT: the result became very simple.
[image: BPMN solved]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a Inclusive gateway here. Join the flows at the "type of employee" location and go through your configuration step and then again fork the path based on the company and the config using a inclusive gateway again. Inclusive gateway makes sure you only wait for executed process paths.

This is supported in [BPMN engine in WSO2 EI](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Creating+a+BPMN+Process) and Activiti, I'm not sure abut other engines.

Comment: As BPMN is a pattern, I'm sure all the tools will at least try to support it. You solved it gracefully. I edited the question with the result.

Thank you!

Comment: Just correcting a thing: I forgot the last forking. But it would be only another gateway pointing to the 2 specific configurations for each company. As the flow tend to be made only for a unique company each time, this solves it completely.